# Can't Integrate Spring Security and Web Logic 7

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, weblogic

Please find my below configuration to integrating Spring Security v3.2.5 with Web Logic Server v7.

I tried to find in couple of places to figure out how integrate but no luck.

When i run my application with below configuration i get  **" No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken"**.

If we look at the configuration have mentioned **"preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider"** as a authentication provider to authentication manager, for preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider have also mentioned "preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService".

Can anyone help me in getting this resolved.

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">


<!-- web sphere configuration start -->

<http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/welcome*" access="permitAll" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/welcome"
        authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
    <custom-filter before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="webspherePreAuthFilter" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/logout" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
    <session-management invalid-session-url="/logout">
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1"
            error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" expired-url="/sessionexpired" />
    </session-management>
</http>

<beans:bean id="filterChainProxy"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <filter-chain-map path-type="ant">
        <!-- <filter-chain pattern="/**"
            filters="sif,webspherePreAuthFilter,logoutFilter,etf,fsi" /> -->
        <filter-chain pattern="/welcome*"
            filters="webspherePreAuthFilter,logoutFilter,etf,fsi" />
    </filter-chain-map>
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService"
        ref="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService" />
</beans:bean>


<beans:bean id="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedGrantedAuthoritiesUserDetailsService" />

<!-- This AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter implementation is based 
    on WebSphere authentication. It will use the WebSphere RunAs user principal 
    name as the pre-authenticated principal. -->


<beans:bean id="webspherePreAuthFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.websphere.WebSpherePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationDetailsSource" ref="authenticationDetailsSource" />
</beans:bean>


<beans:bean id="authenticationDetailsSource"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.websphere.WebSpherePreAuthenticatedWebAuthenticationDetailsSource">
    <beans:property name="webSphereGroups2GrantedAuthoritiesMapper"
        ref="websphereUserGroups2GrantedAuthoritiesMapper" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="websphereUserGroups2GrantedAuthoritiesMapper"
    class="org.springframework.security.core.authority.mapping.SimpleAttributes2GrantedAuthoritiesMapper">
    <beans:property name="convertAttributeToUpperCase"
        value="true" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="preAuthenticatedProcessingFilterEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint" />

<beans:bean id="logoutFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="/" />
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:list>
            <beans:bean
                class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler" />
        </beans:list>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="etf"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter">
    <beans:property name="authenticationEntryPoint"
        ref="preAuthenticatedProcessingFilterEntryPoint" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="fsi"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <beans:property name="accessDecisionManager" ref="httpRequestAccessDecisionManager" />
    <beans:property name="securityMetadataSource">
        <filter-security-metadata-source>
            <intercept-url pattern="/welcome*" access="ROLE_LDP_ADMINS" />
        </filter-security-metadata-source>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="httpRequestAccessDecisionManager"
    class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
    <beans:property name="allowIfAllAbstainDecisions"
        value="false" />
    <beans:property name="decisionVoters">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref bean="roleVoter" />
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="roleVoter"
    class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />


<!-- web sphere configuration ends -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `form-login` included in your configuration, which will create the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` and submit it to the authentication manager. However, the latter only has a `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider` which cannot handle this typeof authentication, hence the error.

You need to add an `AuthenticationProvider` which can handle username/password authentication.

Also, you seem to be mixing both a namespace configuration and an explicit bean configuration. You should choose one or the other - it makes it hard to work out what's actually being used in the example you've posted.

Comment: I tried the approached mentioned by you before posting, everything seems to be working except i can't decode the password. We removed security part and have basic authentication with WebSphere then redirect to other pages within the application. I have got some time to do some R&D on this, i will post my results soon.  Thanking You for your inputs.